# validar repetidos en session

Tags: php, array, validación, session

Cordial saludo, quisiera q por favor me ayudaran con lo siguiente:

tengo los siguientes valores en session, lo que quiero es sumar la cantidad cuando los códigos sean iguales

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Insumo] => TAPA PS BANA-POL TRP MOT
            [Codigo] => 10041142
            [cantidad] => 10
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Insumo] => DIVISION BCL PERFORADA-03
            [Codigo] => 10004797
            [cantidad] => 30
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Insumo] => DIVISION BCL PERFORADA-03
            [Codigo] => 10004797
            [cantidad] => 30
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Insumo] => TAPA PS BANA-POL TRP MOT
            [Codigo] => 10041142
            [cantidad] => 10
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Insumo] => BASE GENERICA
            [Codigo] => 10004984
            [cantidad] => 10
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Insumo] => DIVISION BCL PERFORADA-03
            [Codigo] => 10004797
            [cantidad] => 30
        )

)
```

Comment: Create un array donde la clave sea el código y el valor la suma. Vas recorriendo el array de datos y comparas, si ya existe sumas a la entrada existente y si no añades la entrada

Comment: podrias porfavor ilustrarme con un ejemplo, lo he intentado de la forma en como entendí tu pregunta pero nd aún